# Program for Ubuntu that opens .mbf format?

Tags: files, format, microsoft

I just cleaned up a computer and installed linux on it in place of vista. I made a backup of everything that was needed to be kept on a USB and transferred it to Linux. Now the only files that I have that aren't supported are some Microsoft Money files. The file format is .mbf. Is there an alternative program for Microsoft Money that is available for Ubuntu that can open and read these files just as effectively?

I'll most likely be installing windows 7 over Linux if the version of 7 I have is compatible, since this will be a general house computer with multiple users, so the issue will be resolved that way. However, I'd personally like to keep Linux on it in place of windows, so if there is a program for it I can do that instead.

Thanks for any help! It's always appreciated.

Comment: +1 for "cleaning up" a computer by removing Windows and installing Linux. :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks for that! It's got a power supply issue, but installing linux did everthing i thought it would. No more viruses, the wireless drivers work again, and I'm pretty sure the optical drive works too! I personally don't use Windows for anything more than video games and coding in batch on occasion for fun. This was definitely the right choice :)

Comment: That's funny, because I agree that Linux is better in almost every way, but driver support is where I feel let down!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) before, which I've found excellent. I've never used Microsoft Money though, so I can't compare the features directly. You can [import from Microsoft Money](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q%3a_How_do_I_import_my_data_from_Microsoft_Money.3F), although you'll have to export in QIF format first.

If you hate GnuCash, and really want to go back to Microsoft Money, you can always install it via Wine or a Virtual Windows machine (e.g. through VirtualBox).

Comment: I've been looking around at some programs, and saw GnuCash I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for, I think Scrooge may have what I need. However, the money files aren't mine they're family finances and such, we don't use it anymore it's just a back up so it's not that big a deal. I'm just seeing if there are any programs directly compatible. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Even if they are just backup files, I would still recommend backing up to a more open format like QIF (if I understand correctly), just to future-proof yourself out of proprietary formats. And in any case, if it's "not that big a deal" you shouldn't have this as the reason to move back to Windows. MM can seemingly run pretty well in wine. http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=79

Comment: Like I said the file isn't mine directly and we don't use money anymore, so I don't really care to work too hard to find a way to run it in Linux, I just wanted to see if there was already a program I wasn't aware of. However, I do agree, the file needs to be in a more open format so I can use it and if I can I'll see If I can't get it in a new format first, and maybe tryout GnuCash with it.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused then. When you say they aren't your files, are you saying that you don't have direct access to them? And if you "don't really care to work too hard to find a way to run it in Linux", then why ask here?

Comment: Well it's a "family" computer so the files are my mother's, but we don't use Microsoft Money anymore, however that file contains information from the last time we used it, so it needed to be rescued before fixing the computer. I was just curious about a quick fix for it, like a program that could already open the files as they are. I apologize for the confusion, I was just trying to be general about it. I found a program called Scrooge that seems to recognize the file format it's just encrypted so I can't confirm it yet.

Comment: Okay, no worries. Good luck with Scrooge!